# How to change Jenkins Java Runtime

Tags: java, jenkins

I have Java 10.0.2 on my system but after installing Jenkins and looking in Manage Jenkins and then System Information I get this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5cUN.jpg)

Can anyone help me to chanage java runtime to the latest version(10.0.2)?

I have already set JAVA_HOME, java jdk and jre in windows environment variable.
I have no jdk section in my jenkins configure system.

Comment: Which jenkins version do you have?

Comment: What's in your PATH?

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.121.3

Comment: Does Jenkins support Java 10 yet?  Aren't they working on it currently?

Answer (score 0):

> I have no jdk section in my jenkins configure system.

The JDK can be configured in `Manage Jenkins` > `Global Tool Configuration`.
See [Global Tool Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKQ0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add all different jdk home in global tool configuration and if u have more that one home settings then you will see one option at job level to select JDK.[image]